# How to programmatically change video file duration

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have some videos converted to mp4 using a video converter. The problem is that when I play those videos, they display the wrong duration longer than their actual duration (e.g a video with duration of 30:56:12 shows a duration of 12:45:31 instead). I already know their actual duration, how do I programmatically edit a video's duration info?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I highly recommend you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). This will help you to improve the quality of your questions. **For every question, please show the attempts you have tried and the error messages you get from your attempts.**

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I couldn't find anything rralted to this on the forum. And I honestly, don't know where to start.

Comment: Check out [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv). In simplified terms, it is a wrapper for [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) and other tools.

Comment: I've changed checked it but it's quite confusing. How do I use it in this context?

Comment: I definitely know you can do that with JavaCV but I can't remember the API for this. Try to checkout the docs about metadata processing.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what to do. Instead of trying to change the video duration, I decided to create a trimmed version of the video with the duration I want using ffmpeg